# React-native, Android, keyboard pushing header but header should stay visible

Tags: android, react-native, scroll, keyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1oC2.png)

I have displayed my header "Rozmowy z fizjoterapeutą", I open the input then the keyboard shows and my header is push to the top.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt7bv.png)

```
   <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: '#2D31A6',
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontSize: 24,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        headerShadowVisible: false,
      }}
    >
  <Stack.Screen
        name="Chat"
        component={Chat}
        options={() => ({
          title: 'Rozmowy z fizjoterapeutą',
          contentStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
          },
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

that's my chat component:

```
   <GiftedChat
      renderSend={renderSend}
      renderMessageVideo={renderMessageVideo}
      renderChatFooter={renderChatFooter}
      renderCustomView={renderCustomView}
      messages={messages}
      alwaysShowSend
      onSend={(newMessages) => {
        //@ts-ignore
        onSend(newMessages);
      }}
      user={{
        _id: currentUser,
      }}
    />
```

I have already android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

What I expect:
I open the input, keyboard shows and header "Rozmowy z fizjoterapeutą" is visible.

#edit
Now I see my BottomTabNavigationOptions and I do not see input component.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upNFz.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
In order to get the desired behaviour on the Android platform, 
you must include android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
in the AndroidManifest.xml file. With this setting, 
the system is instructed to use the adjustResize mode to reorganise the 
activity's layout to make room for the soft keyboard.

    import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';
        return (
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
          >
            {/* Here is the code for your current component. */}
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
        
        <GiftedChat
          // ... other props
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        />
        
        <Stack.Screen
         name="Chat"
         component={Chat}
         options={() => ({
         title: 'Rozmowy z fizjoterapeutą',
         contentStyle: {
           backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
         },
         headerStyle: {
          elevation: 0, // This can remove the shadow on the header
         },
       })}
     />
```

See if any of these solutions work for you when you try them. Remember that testing on both Android and iOS is essential because the behaviour could differ across the two systems.

Comment: I edited my post, I see my BottomTabNavigationOptions and I do not see the input component